# Can I have a list of users that like my page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I'm ad administrator of a Facebook page.
I want the list of all users of my page. It's possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, for privacy concerns. You can use the [`page_fan`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_fan/) FQL table or [`/ID/likes`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) to tell if a user is a fan of your page, but you have to know who that user is first (via an install).

Comment: And if I want to check if an user is a fan of my page?

Comment: Use the FQL table above (`SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = '<YOUR PAGE ID>' AND uid = '<UID>'`), or check the contents of the graph request from above.

Comment: @Jimmy : How can you run competitions based of the fact of getting people 'liking' your page? I see many pages doing it...